# SELECT posts, its last 3 comments and count of all comments

Tags: php, sql, select, pdo, comments

SELECT posts, its last 3 comments and count of all comments
My code:

```
SELECT p.*, u.id, u.username username, u.usersurname usersurname, u.usermainphoto userphoto, GROUP_CONCAT(c.text SEPARATOR 'a!k@h#md%o^v&') commenttext,GROUP_CONCAT(c.likes SEPARATOR '-') commentlikes,GROUP_CONCAT(c.dislikes SEPARATOR '-') commentdislikes, GROUP_CONCAT(c.commentdate) commentdate, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.username) commentauthorname, GROUP_CONCAT(c.anonim) commentanonym, GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) commentid, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.id) commentauthorid, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.usersurname) commentauthorsurname, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.usermainphoto) commentauthorphoto, GROUP_CONCAT(c.commentphotoid) commentphotoid
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post = p.postid AND c.commentdel=0
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = p.postauthorid
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = c.author
WHERE p.postwallid = :id AND p.postdel=0
GROUP BY postid
ORDER BY postid DESC
```

it gives me all comments, but I need only 3

Comment: First, for the GROUP BY, you should only select raw fields that are in the GROUP BY section, or the fields you select should be though an aggregation function (min, max, sum, etc...). Then, I see no COUNT function in your query, so you won't be able to count the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a timestamp or counter of something to determine which comments are the three you want. Add that column name between the angle brackets below.

```
SELECT p.*, u.id, u.username username, u.usersurname usersurname, u.usermainphoto userphoto, GROUP_CONCAT(c.text SEPARATOR 'a!k@h#md%o^v&') commenttext,GROUP_CONCAT(c.likes SEPARATOR '-') commentlikes,GROUP_CONCAT(c.dislikes SEPARATOR '-') commentdislikes, GROUP_CONCAT(c.commentdate) commentdate, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.username) commentauthorname, GROUP_CONCAT(c.anonim) commentanonym, GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) commentid, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.id) commentauthorid, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.usersurname) commentauthorsurname, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.usermainphoto) commentauthorphoto, GROUP_CONCAT(c.commentphotoid) commentphotoid
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post = p.postid AND c.commentdel = 0
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = p.postauthorid
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = c.author
WHERE p.postwallid = :id AND p.postdel = 0
    and (
        select count(*) from comments as c2
        where c2.postid = p.postid and c2.commentdel = 0
        and c2.<timestamp> <= c.timestamp
    ) < 3
GROUP BY postid
ORDER BY postid DESC
```

Edit: I didn't add the count of all comments. I think you can easily add it with another subquery in the select list but I know MySQL people don't like subqueries very much.

```
(
select count(*) from comments as c2
where c2.postid = c.postid and c2.commentdel = 0
) as comment_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I add in SELECT count(postid) as all_comments and at the end LIMIT 0, 3

```
SELECT count(postid) as all_comments, p.*, u.id, u.username username, u.usersurname usersurname, u.usermainphoto userphoto, GROUP_CONCAT(c.text SEPARATOR 'a!k@h#md%o^v&') commenttext,GROUP_CONCAT(c.likes SEPARATOR '-') commentlikes,GROUP_CONCAT(c.dislikes SEPARATOR '-') commentdislikes, GROUP_CONCAT(c.commentdate) commentdate, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.username) commentauthorname, GROUP_CONCAT(c.anonim) commentanonym, GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) commentid, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.id) commentauthorid, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.usersurname) commentauthorsurname, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.usermainphoto) commentauthorphoto, GROUP_CONCAT(c.commentphotoid) commentphotoid
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post = p.postid AND c.commentdel=0
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = p.postauthorid
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = c.author
WHERE p.postwallid = :id AND p.postdel=0
GROUP BY postid
ORDER BY postid DESC
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: In this situation, you limited POSTS, but I need to limit comments.